# Swift iOS -DispatchGroup with URLSession is locking other parts of app that it is not located in

Tags: ios, swift, loops, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

I have an array of up to 6 images. I use a loop to loop through all of the images, turn them into metadata, send the metadata to Storage and then when done I send the url strings to Firebase Database.

I'm using DispatchGroup to control the loop as the Url is changed to Data so I can send the data to Firebase Storage.

If this loop is happening in tabOne, if i go back and forth to tabTwo or tabThree, when the loop finishes and the alert appears, tabTwo is temporarily locked or tabThree gets temporarily locked for around 2-3 seconds. I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong?

I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using a custom alert instead of the UIAlertController. It's just some UIViews and a button, it's nothing special so I didn't include the code.

```
var urls = [URL]()
picUUID = UUID().uuidString
dict = [String:Any]()

let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
var count = 0

for url in urls{

    myGroup.enter() // enter group here
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, let _ = error else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.sendDataToStorage("\(self.picUUID)_\(self.count).jpg", picData: data)
                self.count += 1
            }
     }).resume()

    // send dictionary data to firebase when loop is done
    myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.sendDataToFirebaseDatabase()
        self.count = 0
    }
}

func sendDataToStorage(_ picId: String, picData: Data?){

    dict.updateValue(picId, forKey:"picId_\(count)")

    let picRef = storageRoot.child("pics")
    picRef.putData(picData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

        if let picUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{

             self.dict.updateValue(picUrl, forKey:"picUrl_\(count)")
             self.myGroup.leave() // leave group here
        }else{
             self.myGroup.leave() // leave group if picUrl is nil
        }
    }
}

func sendDataToFirebaseDatabase(){

    let ref = dbRoot.child("myRef")
    ref.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
         displaySuccessAlert()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about Firebase, but you are dispatching your `sendDataToFirebaseDatabase` method to main queue which probably explains why your UI becomes unresponsive.

Dispatch `sendDataToFirebaseDatabase` to a background queue and only dispatch your `displaySuccessAlert` back to main queue.

Comment: Once i added the background queue I got a bunch of purple suggestions saying I need to put other things on the main queue such as sendButtonTapped.isUserInteractionEnabled = false. I also wants me to put the alert on the button, view, and the anchors on the main queue

Comment: are you still there? I notice the task takes forever to complete. It moves really really slow now

Comment: What part exactly, syncinc to Firebase?

Comment: I found out the issue. When a photo is taken I save the images to the document's directory and then use the url from the document's directory to display the photo. The problem was when I saved the photo I used UIJpegImageRepresentation and the compression quality was set at 1.0. I reduced it to 0.5 and it's 10x faster. Thanks for the help and enjoy your day!